# Gridview taking more time to bind

Tags: asp.net, gridview, time-complexity

I am fetching data from stored procedure and showing in the grid view.

My sql query takes max 1 sec to execute but while binding to gridview it takes more time .

In my page only one gridview is present. and the load time of my page is 10 sec :(

so how to increase my loading time.(i searched on google and didn't find any good solution :( )

My Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStatusStatistics" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CssClass="grid" OnRowCreated="gvStatusStatistics_RowCreated">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PNSC_Leads_LeadStatus">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlLeadStatus" ForeColor="#000000" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TranslatedStatus") %>'
                        NavigateUrl='<%# string.Concat("~/ViewLeads.aspx?LeadStatusDefinition=", Eval("Status")) %>'
                        ToolTip="" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PNSC_Leads_NumberOfLeads">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlLeadsCount" ForeColor="#000000" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value") %>'
                        NavigateUrl='<%# string.Concat("~/ViewLeads.aspx?LeadStatusDefinition=", Eval("Status")) %>'
                        ToolTip="" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


protected void gvStatusStatistics_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.Write("gvStatusStatistics_RowCreated", "Start");

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int CellCounter = 0;

            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                CellCounter++;

                // track which row this is 
                if (CellCounter % 2 == 0)
                {
                    // change the alternating one background color
                    cell.CssClass = GridCellAlternating1Css;
                }
                else
                {
                    // change the alternating zero background color
                    cell.CssClass = GridCellAlternating0Css;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help to solve this.

Thanks

below line taking more time

```
using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
{

}
```

Comment: Please post the code for `gvStatusStatistics_RowCreated` method.

Comment: please check add row created method

Comment: Well it looks like your `RowCreated` method is not doing much that would cause a 10 second bottleneck. Have you put break points in your code to see if it is slow to retrieve the data or whether it is slow to process the data?

Comment: oho sorry.

actually while fetching data its taking time :(. When i execute the stored proc. in sql server management studio its showing 1 sec. but while fetching from code its taking 6 sec :( .

Can you help me solve this.

Comment: Post the code for your call to the stored procedure.

Comment: Did you try **SqlDataSource** instead of **DataReader**?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't see you set **DataSourceID** in GridView and you have used **ExecuteReader** method, then I assumed that you use other ways to bind data to GridView. Is it possible for you to allow paging in the GridView?